# Analysis of average payload size in DataDog

Tags: datadog

To estimate the cost of cloud storage service, I need average size of the request payload for my API. API request and response are logged in DataDog. For each request, I want to see the Content-Length header from request headers. I can see that under the RequestHeaders facet which has all other request headers.

Is there anyway to extract Content-Length from RequestHeaders value(JSON) for each request log, so I can then find out average payload size ? There are different types of API requests, and I want to find out average payload size for each one of them.

Comment: Did you found how to do it?

Comment: Yeah, but not directly in Data dog, I downloaded all logs in CSV, then some excel work.